# Updating wrong User with devise after_create in user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, after-save

I have set up a `referral_code`, and want to add 1 to the user whose `referral_code` it is, after someone signs up. There are no errors with the code, but the `referral_count` only updates the first user, no matter what user number is put in as the `referral_code`.

User model:

```
after_create :check_referral_code

def check_referral_code
  if self.referral_code != nil
    self.referral_code = self.referral_code.strip
    referral_code = self.referral_code
    length = referral_code.length
    referral_code = referral_code[5..length]
    @user_referral_code = referral_code.to_i 

    if User.exists?(id: @user_referral_code)
      referral_user = User.find_by(@user_referral_code)
      referral_user.referral_count = referral_user.referral_count + 1
      referral_user.save
    end
  end
end
```

In devise `sign_up` form:

```html
<div class="form-group input-group-lg">
  <%= f.text_field :referral_code, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Referral Code (ex.LEX50456)"%>
</div>
```

Comment: Use byebug to debug the code

Comment: Hi, how are you generating the refferal_code and what does your user schema look like?